# cassandra -tokens and org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: For input string:

Tags: cassandra

whats the deal with Cassandra?

From the token tool with 2 nodes and on the second cluster I get the  below error.

```
   initial_token: 85070591730234615865843651857942052864

INFO [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:39,670 CassandraDaemon.java (line 130) Logging initialized
 INFO [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:39,716 YamlConfigurationLoader.java (line 76) Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
 INFO [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:40,407 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 141) Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:40,408 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 142) Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
 INFO [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:40,409 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 182) DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
 INFO [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:40,409 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 196) disk_failure_policy is stop
 INFO [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:40,417 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 266) Global memtable threshold is enabled at 122MB
 INFO [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:40,609 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 399) Not using multi-threaded compaction
ERROR [main] 2014-02-25 01:15:40,612 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 115) Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: For input string: "85070591730234615865843651857942052864"
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$1.validate(Murmur3Partitioner.java:178)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:438)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:110)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:151)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:462)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:552)
```

Answer (score 6):

These aren't valid Murmur3Partitioner tokens, they are RandomPartitioner tokens. Take a look at these [DataStax docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens_c.html) on generating murmur3 tokens, or if you do want to use RandomPartitioner then edit your `partitioner` setting in cassandra.

Just for a clear comparison

```
Murmur3 Partitioner    | Random Partitioner
------------------------------------------------------------
-9223372036854775808   | 0
-4611686018427387904   | 42535295865117307932921825928971026432
-0                     | 85070591730234615865843651857942052864
-4611686018427387904   | 127605887595351923798765477786913079296
```

You can generate murmur3 tokens using python (n is the number of nodes in the dc):

```
python -c 'print [str(((2**64 / n) * i) - 2**63) for i in range(n)]'
# eg for 4 nodes...
python -c 'print [str(((2**64 / 4) * i) - 2**63) for i in range(4)]'
```

Comment: Thanx man, that helped me a lot. Can you please tell me the benefit of RandomPartitioner over Murmur3Partitioner. Also, when i used to run `bin/nodetool ring` command on M.P. it used to return many rows. But now when i run the same command while using R.P it return only two rows. Why is it so?

Comment: Murmr is better than random, it allowed to achieve better data distribution.  Nodetool ring will return 256 x number of nodes if you have virtual nodes on which is the default. Use nodetool status instead.